# How to create and start Task, and have a completion handler, which runs on completion?

Tags: asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

...without `async` `await`...

I would like to *demonstrate* the classic completion handler logic with `Task` library. (not with the pure `Thread` object) So I would like to create a `Task` instance, run it (against the default thread pool, or any way), and have a completion handler, which runs (probably on the Task's thread) on completion and access to the result.

(I do know now we can use `async await`, also know about marshaling, also know about ASP.NET threads and contexts, please do not explain those.)

Comment: What's the actual problem you want to solve? `without async await` why? What marshalling do you refer to? You don't need a completion handler anyway, you can use `ContinueWith` which in turn returns a Task. `async/await` removes the needed for the long `.ContinueWith(t=> { var result=t.Result; ...;}).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith()` people had to write before 2012. `t` is the completed parent task

Comment: Exceptions aren't propagated they way they are in `async/await`. If the parent task fails `t.Result` will throw so you need to check if the parent task failed. You can specify that a specific `ContinueWith` will only run on success or failure. In general, you end up with very complicated code very quickly

Comment: `which runs (probably on the Task's thread)` that's another problem - tasks aren't threads. You can't think of them as threads at all, or talk about the task's thread. They're a job object that runs on whatever thread the TaskScheduler decides. `ContinueWith` will run its own delegate as another task which will be scheduled according to either the default TaskScheduler or the one you pass to `ContinueWith`. You can specify that you want to run on the same thread that processed the previous task if you want through flags, to avoid thread switching

Comment: I have no "problem". Instead I would like to demonstrate a workflow of parallel processing, as it is in its core.  I intentionally wrote italic the word demonstrate. Still in case you do agree even with a demonstration, you can ask why I would demonstrate such a thing... well, I would like explain to my students, how a multithreaded workflow works, to prevent they dumbed down, to use async await like a trained monkey....

Comment: The problem isn't italics, the problem is that this question isn't very clear, and I've used with Tasks for 2 years before `async/await` came along. A Task is a Promise, not a thread. It can represent a parallel or asynchronous IO operation. It gets scheduled to run or get awaited by a Task Scheduler, it doesn't schedule itself. When that promise completes, `ContinueWith` will create a new promise with the previous one's result. That one too will be  scheduled by the Task Scheduler. There's no marshalling of the result between threads, if that's what you mean by marshalling

Comment: Stephen Toub wrote a series of articles explaining all this in the [.NET Parallel Programming Team blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/). `ContinueWith` first appears in June 2008](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/useful-abstractions-enabled-with-continuewith/). Depending on what you mean by "parallel workflow" you may want to look at the TPL Dataflow library too. Tasks are one-off promises while Dataflow processes a stream of messages/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to demonstrate the classic completion handler logic with Task library.

I really don't think this is very useful. It sounds like you're describing continuation passing style, which was not widely adopted among .NET libraries. There was one HTTP library using it, but other than that I did not see much adoption of that pattern in .NET at all. On the other hand, JavaScript (particularly server-side JS) did use CPS quite a bit.

That said, if you really want to do it, you can:

```
public static void Run<T>(Func<T> action, Action<Exception> onError, Action<T> onComplete)
{
  Task.Run(action).ContinueWith(
      t =>
      {
        T result;
        try
        {
          result = t.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          onError(ex);
          return;
        }
        onComplete(result);
      },
      default,
      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
      TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: many thx. That is it, although I did not mean to marshal back the continuation handler to the calling thread, instead thought about purest workflow, when the continuation runs on the other started thread, I did not specified it, its true. Of course that may raise concurrency scenarios, or can be even impossible if the used objects are not thread safe by their design.

Comment: This code sample will not marshal back to the original thread. It will run the continuation on the thread pool thread that ran the action.

Comment: True, I confused the options